# OpenVPN AUTH failure, but login data is correct

Tags: vpn, authentication, certificate, openvpn

I installed OpenVPN on both windows 7 and ubuntu 12.10. In both cases I have the same problem. I have a .ovpn file and a .crt file which I need to connect to the vpn. I also have a username/password combination. When I run OpenVPN (in admin/sudo mode) using those files I get the error: `AUTH: Received AUTH_FAILED control message`

I am however certain that my username and passowrd are correct. My question is now whether there is something else that can cause an AUTH failure?

In ubuntu I run openvpn from the terminal (since running it from the network manager applet did not work either).

The contents of the .ovpn file are as follows:

```
client
proto tcp
dev tun
remote virtualwall.test.ibbt.be 443
persist-key
persist-tun
# uncomment if you use a proxy:
# http-proxy-retry
# http-proxy proxy2.intec.ugent.be 8080
cipher DES-EDE3-CBC  # Triple-DES
comp-lzo
ca /home/kv/Documents/vwall-ca.crt
script-security 2

auth-user-pass

# uncomment if you use linux
cd /etc/openvpn/
```

Comment: You can try commenting "script-security 2".

Comment: Is the server your own or does it belong to somebody else ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I'm hoping that posting may help future Googlers find happiness.
I had similar problems with my VPN provider (ProXPN).  I was CERTAIN that I was using the same user-name/password that successfully got me into my account on their website, but the VPN client kept AUTH_FAILED.  Turns out, my password was 12-characters long, which works fine on the web site.  I reduced the password to 8-characters and the VPN client connected and authenticated perfectly!

Comment: expanding on the above: after chatting with the VPN provider's tech support, we determined that, in my case, there was no problem with the password length, but special characters in the password _and email/username_ were causing the problem.